# Google+ sharing not populating Image, title, description

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to use Google+ share on my website. I am using one anchor tag.

```
<a target="_blank" id="btnGoogleShare" href="#" runat="server">
Google+</a>
```

In code behind I am setting Href as

```
btnGoogleShare.Href = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=[My site url]/page?_i=10"
```

I've added following tags in head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
</script>   
<meta itemprop="name" content="Sample Title">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Sample Description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="[My site url]/SampleImage.jpg">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://plus.google.com/share?url=http//:MySite.com/page?_i=10>
<meta property="og:title" content="Sample Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Sample Description">
<meta property="og:image" content="[my site URL]/SampleImage.jpg">
```

I am running my website in localhost in visual studio. When I click on link I am getting only url in google plus share dialog. title, description, image is not populating. Any Idea? It may be because I am running in dev environment in visual studio using localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running my website in localhost in visual studio.

Google+ populates the field by fetching the page and parsing the details via Google servers. If the URL is not live and publicly accessible on the internet, Google+ sharing will only show the URL.

Comment: Thanks Abraham, I was not aware of this thing. So it means if I deploy my changes to server then afterwards it will pick all correct information automatically or I need to do any additional things. The code written by me is ok? Please suggest if any changes are required.

Comment: As long as you follow the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) you should be fine. Once your updates are deployed you can test them using the [structured data tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).